# How to parse xml with javascript find method?

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing

i working on parsing xml with JavaScript.

my currently codes;

```
xmlDoc = $.parseXML( fnSuccess.__batchResponses[0].response.body ),
            $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
            $errormessage = $xml.find( "message" );
```

$errormessage.text() and its returning this:

```
<code>SY/530</code>
<message xml:lang="en">S:W5:102 0010017899</message>
<innererror>
<transactionid>A831E4E4ADFDF1998E50005056AA3F7A</transactionid>
<timestamp/><Error_Resolution><SAP_Transaction/><SAP_Note/></Error_Resolution>
<errordetails><errordetail><

code>W5/102</code>
<message>S:W5:102 0010017899</message>

<propertyref/>
<severity>error</severity>
</errordetail><errordetail>

<code>W5/102</code>
<message>S:W5:102 0010017899</message>
<propertyref/>
<severity>error</severity>
</errordetail><errordetail>

<code>/IWBEP/CX_SD_GEN_DPC_BUSINS</code>
<message> --- Order is checked and approved ----</message>
<propertyref/>
<severity>error</severity>
</errordetail></errordetails>
</innererror></error>
```

but i wanna get only line of --- Order is checked and approved ---- `/IWBEP/CX_SD_GEN_DPC_BUSINS`.

how can i get it with which parameter on $errormessage = $xml.find( "message" );

thanks..

Comment: What hv u tried so far? what error is shown with your code?

Comment: What is "fnSuccess.__batchResponses[0].response.body" ?

Comment: i just use   $errormessage = $xml.find( "message" ); method and get all error messages. but i want get only line of <message> --- Order is checked and approved ----</message> . how to parse it? i tried  $xml.find( "message" ).eq(3) and its work but error lenghts can change

Comment: grimbode its returning an xml page. i shared returned page.

Comment: yep i tried.  its returning all messages. but i want get spesicly message.

Comment: i shared returned errormesage.text() on my question already

Comment: You can also use the getElementsByTagName("message") function on your xmldoc. That should give you an array of all <message> tags that you can sort through to get the message that you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$errormessage.find('message').eq(2).text()
```

Will return: "--- Order is checked and approved ----"

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bgn7khao/1/)

Update: You have a acouple solutions. If your error message will always start with '---' then:

```
$errormessage.find('message').filter(function(){
    return ($(this).text().trim().substring(0, 3) == '---')
}).text()
```

[Demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/bgn7khao/3/)

If you want to go through with the code message "/IWBEP/CX_SD_GEN_DPC_BUSINS" then:

```
$errormessage.find('code').filter(function(){
    return ($(this).text() == '/IWBEP/CX_SD_GEN_DPC_BUSINS')
}).next().text()
```

[Demo3](http://jsfiddle.net/bgn7khao/4/)

Comment: i tried it but he number of message can changable.. can i call it with get message after code>W5/102</code> ?  or find('message') start with ---order?

Comment: Will this "/IWBEP/CX_SD_GEN_DPC_BUSINS" always be the same?

Comment: yepp. thanksssss its worked:)   .next('message').text() is it work? bkz now its not stabilite. maybe we can most spesifcly query..

Answer (score 2):

Here is my version - took a while so someone posted while I was playing too

shows

`--- Order is checked and approved ----`

```js
    var xml = '<error><code>SY/530</code><message xml:lang="en">S:W5:102 0010017899</message><innererror><transactionid>A831E4E4ADFDF1998E50005056AA3F7A</transactionid><timestamp/><Error_Resolution><SAP_Transaction/><SAP_Note/></Error_Resolution><errordetails><errordetail><code>W5/102</code><message>S:W5:102 0010017899</message><propertyref/><severity>error</severity></errordetail><errordetail><code>W5/102</code><message>S:W5:102 0010017899</message><propertyref/><severity>error</severity></errordetail><errordetail><code>/IWBEP/CX_SD_GEN_DPC_BUSINS</code><message> --- Order is checked and approved ----</message><propertyref/><severity>error</severity></errordetail></errordetails></innererror></error>'
    
    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),$xml = $(xmlDoc);
    var messages = $xml.find("message");
    var message = messages.filter(function(i,msg) {
        console.log(msg)
         return msg.textContent.indexOf("---") !=-1;
    });
    console.log(message[0].textContent)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```